# Disallow or replace certain characters in string with Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is it possible to disallow or replace certain characters in string with Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules?

For example disallow the "<" and ">" characters?

Or replace the "<" character with NOTHING ?

When I use `".validate": "!newData.val().matches(/(<|>)/)"` in the top level of my rules it prevents all kind of new data. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely possible with Firebase Realtime Database security rules.

You can use the .validate rule to specify a regex pattern that data must match. For your specific examples, you could do:

```
Disallow <: .validate(!newData.hasChildren() && !newData.val().matches('<'))
Replace < with >: .validate(!newData.hasChildren() && newData.val().replace('<', '>').matches('[your-regex-here]'))
```

The !newData.hasChildren() condition is included above to prevent the rule from being bypassed by writing nested data.

Comment: Thank you. Will this work with any string which includes any "<" character? Or just when the string is only one "<" character? I need to look for any "<" in every possible string.

Comment: To disallow < anywhere in a string, you could use:
!newData.val().matches('<')

To replace < with > anywhere in a string, you could use:
newData.val().replace('<', '>')

Comment: It seems there is no such thing as "replace" in Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules. And the syntax has to be like this: ```".validate": "newData.isString()"```

Comment: When I use ```".validate": "!newData.val().matches(/(<|>)/)"``` in the top level of my rules it prevents all kind of new data. Can someone tell me why?